# activate diffrent conda installation from sshfs

Tags: ssh, installation, config, conda, remote-debugging

Good Day to you all,

I was wondering if it is possible to use a shared Conda installation on a remote machine. The remote machine is running ubuntu 12 (I have no influence). I use in Windows 10, with the latest updates.

Since it is Ubuntu 12, I cannot run the visual studio code remote ssh. But that's what I kind of want.

So far I installed miniconda3 and set up sshfs for windows and mapped "the folder".

If I use install conda on Linux/Ubuntu, I can modify the .bashrc file and change the conda installation path:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/[...]/sharedConda/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/[...]/sharedConda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/[...]/sharedConda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/[...]/sharedConda/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

then it works fine.

Now my questions:

Is this also possible under windows? and how? is there something similar to .bashrc?

Comment: You want to use the conda env from the ubuntu machine on your windows by mounting the folder(in windows using sshfs) where conda and the env are installed?

Comment: Yes, exactly @FlyingTeller

Comment: I am not so familiar with the restrictions that ubuntu12 brings with it, but why are you not able to run visual studio code through `ssh` with x-forwarding (using something like moba-X-Term on the windows machine)?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I set up moba-X-Term, however my connection is really slow - that doesn't make any fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will not be able to get this to work. Starting with the python interpreter that is installed in the Ubuntu environment, it is a binary compiled for a linux system. You can mount the folder in windows, but you will not be able to execute the binary nonetheless. The same goes for any module that you have installed that relies on compiled `cython` or shared libraries. All these things will have been specifically compiled for the ubuntu machine.

You can modify the `PYTHONPATH` on your windows machine to point to the `site-packages` of the ubuntu environment, but you will not be able to import any packages that are not pure python.

Instead, you could export the conda environment on the ubuntu machine `conda env export > environment.yml` and then create it on your windows machine: `conda env create -f environment.yml`